# Mocking virtual method on already-instantiated concrete class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, azure-service-fabric

I'm looking to write some unit tests for Service Fabric actors. The guidance [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-how-to-unit-test-stateful-services) suggests using a NuGet package called [ServiceFabric.Mocks](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.Mocks) that simplifies spinning up mocks of the various Service Fabric entities.

All this makes sense so far. I can use the following to spin up a concrete implementation for my actor:

```
private MyActor CreateActor(ActorId id) 
{
  Func<ActorService, ActorId, ActorBase> factory = (service, actorId) => new MyActor(service, id);
  var svc = MockActorServiceFactory.CreateActorServiceForActor<MyActor>(factory);
  var actor = svc.Activate(id);

  return actor;
}
```

As long as I stick to the example in the package docs and test the result of a single method, I'm set. However, I've got a method that calls another method in the actor and uses its result. It looks like the following:

```
public class MyActor : Actor, IMyActor 
{
  public async Task<string> DoThis()
  {
    var result = await DoThat();

    //...
  }

  public virtual async Task<string> DoThat()
  {
     //...
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to mock the DoThat method in my actor so I might test the DoThis method, but it's not clear how to do that given that the result of the ServiceFabric.Mocks is a concrete object.

The only two ways I see to move forward are:
1) Identify some way to create a mock of an already instantiated class
2) Recreate the functionality of this mocks library myself so I might mock out the method before the concrete object is created

Is there any way to go about approaching #1 without resorting to #2?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a mock, you could create a new class, near your unit test, that inherits from your `MyActor` and override the `DoThat` implementation for test purposes:

```
private class MyTestActor : MyActor
{
   public string Result {get; set;} = "ok";
   public override Task<string> DoThat() { return Task.FromResult(Result); }
}
```

Your test code would be like this:

```
private MyActor CreateActor(ActorId id) 
{
  Func<ActorService, ActorId, ActorBase> factory = (service, actorId) => new MyTestActor(service, id);
  var svc = MockActorServiceFactory.CreateActorServiceForActor<MyTestActor>(factory);
  var actor = svc.Activate(id);

  return actor;
}
```

Or, you could move the logic from `DoThat` into a separate class with an interface, use dependency injection and pass in different implementations for test / real runs.